# Recuperar Input file dinâmico via php

Tags: php

Crio blocos de campos dinâmico, com dois inputs e um file, desta forma:

```
$('#input_nova').click(function()
{
    var total_item = $(".input_item").length ;
    $('#input_container').append(
        '<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 input_item">\
            <h5>Título</h5>\
            <input type="text" name="imovel_input_titulo['+total_item+']" id=""/>\
            <h5>Imagem</h5>\
            <input type="file" name="imovel_input_imagem['+total_item+']" id=""/>\
            <h5>Descrição</h5>\
            <textarea name="imovel_input_descricao['+total_item+']" ></textarea>\
        </div>'
    );
});
```

No post através do `foreach` os dados dos `inputs` são verificados sem problema:

```
$input_titulo       = $_POST['imovel_input_titulo'];
$input_descricao    = $_POST['imovel_input_descricao'];
$input_imagem       = $_FILES['imovel_input_imagem'];
$total              = count($input_titulo);

for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++)
{
    printf("Título : %s <br />", $input_titulo[$i]);
    printf("Descrição : %s <br />", $input_descricao[$i]);
    printf("Imagem : %s <br />", $input_imagem['imovel_input_imagem']['name'][$i]);
    echo '<br /><hr />';
}
```

Mas, no `input file`, retorna esse erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: imovel_input_imagem

Comment: O seu form possui `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: Opa, possui sim, tenho outros campos que não são dinamicos de imagem, e são upados normalmente

Comment: O envio é via Ajax?

Comment: Via post normal

Comment: Tem algo erro, faz um `var_dump($_FILES);`, tenho certeza que você fez alguma confusão, posta o resultado do var_dump.

Comment: Enviado duas imagens, o retorno foi esse. `Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => 335114.jpg [1] => 335114.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg [1] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => D:\Desenvolvimento\tmp\php3B67.tmp [1] => D:\Desenvolvimento\tmp\php3B68.tmp ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 147631 [1] => 147631 ) ) 
`

Comment: Você não fez `var_dump($_FILES);`? Você mudou o código para outra coisa? Porque essa resposta parece que você fez algo como `var_dump($_FILES['imovel_input_imagem']);`, se _FILES estivesse correto teria retornado o nome do input juntto no var_dump. Verifica pq vc fez algo errado nesse debug.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69514/discussion-between-snniffer-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Comment: dump: `array(1) { ["imovel_input_imagem"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(29) "1_IqqAaP4KoJfaxTEOlPHEbA.jpeg" [1]=> string(10) "335114.jpg" } ["type"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" [1]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(47) "D:\Desenvolvimento\tmp\phpF886.tmp" [1]=> string(47) "D:\Desenvolvimento\tmp\phpF887.tmp" } ["error"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(202992) [1]=> int(147631) } } }

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido

```
    for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++)
    {
        printf("Título : %s <br />", $input_titulo[$i]);
        printf("Descrição : %s <br />", $input_descricao[$i]);
        printf("Imagem : %s <br />", $_FILES['imovel_input_imagem']['name'][$i]);
        echo '<br /><hr />';
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que percebi faltou o índice no campo de imagem, tente adicionar:

```
 for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++)
        {
            printf("Título : %s <br />", $input_titulo[$i]);
            printf("Descrição : %s <br />", $input_descricao[$i]);
            printf("Imagem : %s <br />", $input_imagem[$i]['imovel_input_imagem']['name'][$i]);
            echo '<br /><hr />';
        }
```

Comment: `Notice: Undefined offset:` na linha do `print` da imagem

Comment: da um var_dump no $_POST  e vê se está retornando mesmo @sNniffer